# How to Understand Macros-definitions unchanged

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

actually i have a code which has macros serially

what i want to know here is how does they really work on the code because i want to write my own pre processor by seeing the below results im really surprised

```
#define int char     //macro1
#define char float   //macro2
#define float int    //macro3
main()
{
 int x;
 char y;
 float z;
}
```

what i expected the code to be in the file after pre processing is all three variables x,y,z as int,int,int

but surprising(to me) the types are unchanged why so? could any one explain me in detail how  does the macros come in to play during pre processing

Comment: did you tried to do just one of them? like just '#define float int' without the other two?

Comment: There are various resources online (like http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html) that provide an in-depth explanation of how the preprocessor works, specifically as relates to macros.  You'd probably find it useful to read them...

Comment: These macros are horrible. I hope they're not going to be used in real code. To answer your question, it's probably related to the order you give your macros in. Try reversing the order of the definitions and see what you get.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel i have tried them but what interestingly happening is with multiple macros my doubt really is how macros work on code does each macro is checked entire code or the macro substitution happens dynamically

Comment: @reuben thanks this will definitely help me in my project

Answer (score 4):

Macro expansion continues until expansion is completed, and macros cannot be recursively expanded. Each macro you defined expands to another macro, but stops when the expansion would become recursive, which means the types remain unchanged.

Comment: If recursive expansion were allowed, there would be no way to stop it. It would infinitely loop through changing `int` to `char` to `float` to `int`.

Comment: got it no more looping allowed,and substitution stops when when it again tried to change with same thanks @user315052